# Can I instantiate an object by the class name in pure Kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin

What is the equivalent of the following Java code in pure Kotlin?

```
Class.forName(className).newInstance()
```

Suppose we are in a Kotlin multi-platform project.

Answer (score 5):

This will just work as-is in Kotlin on the JVM, as Kotlin is compiled to JVM classes which are available via Java reflection, so you can use this line of code in Kotlin as well.

For other Kotlin platforms (Kotlin/JS, Kotlin/Native), there's currently no proper reflection support, so you can't do that when running on those platforms.

Comment: True it works on the JVM, however as of today (2023) method Class.newInstance() is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

There is no multiplatform solution, however for JAVA you should create a new instance from the declared constructor:

```
Class.forName(className).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
```

Comment: As the other answer explains this won't work in Kotlin on any other platform than Java. Did this change since that answer? If so, then please explain why/how this now works.

Comment: The answer from 2018 does not explain that "this line of code" today uses deprecated methods.